# AWS Site Slowness (LAMP)

Tags: php, performance, amazon-web-services

My site is experiencing slowness ever since we moved over to AWS from a different server provider - the site is built on a LAMP stack and we're not sure what is causing the slowness. **We did not experience such significant lag on the previous server.**

Some notes:

- The site runs fine on a localhost environment which is why we think it's something with our AWS setup (however, feel free to correct me)

  - For reference, the site IS image-heavy, uses PHP5.6 (so it's outdated), and DOES use a few SELECT * queries on various pages, etc.
  - We just don't believe the above is the issue, but please let me know if there's often dispensaries between localhost and production environments, because this is the first time I'm experiencing such.
  - As noted, we did not experience such significant lag on the previous server.
- We have tried asking AWS support, where they made a suggestion which made a noticeable difference to the site, but the site still experiences around 5sec lag time per page. They now say they can't find any reason for the lags, but at the same time because of the lags, our site is experiencing much lower traffic (most of the lags occurred with high traffic volume)
- We've updated the aws settings a few different times in a few different ways, such as:

  - Updating the EC2 instance
  - Updating RDS
  - Implementing this: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/
- Some people have reported that there's no lagtime unless a user logs into the site

Any suggestions are helpful! We are hoping to not have to move the site's server again.

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. What analysis have you carried out? Using Chrome, post a screenshot of the lag from the network tab. Add details about what size your RDS and EC2 instances are. Also, where is your domain and are you using Route53? Have you looking into checking the speed of the SQL statements?

Comment: I'm voting this as offtopic for stackoverflow, but go check out your EC2 CPUCreditBalance in cloud watch if you're using a "burstable" instance type (t2)